# How do I edit a commit with interactive rebase as uncommited?

Tags: git

I would like to use an interactive rebase to edit a previous commit, but when I enter the edit mode for that commit all the files have been committed.

I know I can make changes and amend the commit but I want all the changes uncommitted initially (staged or otherwise) so I can edit it as if it was moments before it was originally committed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

Imagine `git rebase --interactive` gives you this list:

```
pick 3d15626 first
pick 7911b8b second
pick 60d94b4 third
```

and you now want to edit the second commit in its un-committed state. For this change its line like the this:

```
pick 3d15626 first
exec git cherry-pick --no-commit 7911b8b && false
pick 60d94b4 third
```

What this line does:

- instead of picking the commit normally `git cherry-pick` is executed
- `git cherry-pick` will apply the "second" commit (note the same commit hash used) to the index and the working tree, preload the commit message but not commit (`--no-commit`)
- `&& false` ensures that the executed command "fails" by returning a failing exit code. This forces `git rebase` to break after this line to let you "fix" the problem, i.e. you can now edit the commit
- after you are done editing you can `git commit` it again. The editor will automatically contain the original commit message thanks to `git cherry-pick`
- after you committed the commit and the index is clean again you can continue with `git rebase --continue`

Comment: thank you for your answer acran - out of curiosity - where did you learn to do this wtihin the edit--todo file? I was not aware that it could be done. I have tried your methods: the changes were staged, but i simply unstaged and redited them etc. and then handled the merge conflicts when the rebase was continued. works ok.

Comment: where I learned this? Years of git usage and some curiosity I guess :D
If you'd rather like all changes unstaged, you can add a `git reset -- .` to the line. `git reset` will unstage all changes, `-- .` is there to only reset the files but keep the preloaded commit massage.

Comment: Thanks @acran this does the job great. I will award you the bounty giving this great contribution from a new member. Git 2.23. has just been released, it's likely a workaround isn't needed anymore with [git-restore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57507293/1214214)

Comment: I was hoping to use this on every commit with `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="sed -i 's/^pick \([[:digit:][:lower:]]\{7\}\).*/exec git cherry-pick --no-commit \1 \&\& false/'" git rebase --interactive main` and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can at least reset to the previous commit, add everything and commit: you will then able to set again the commit message.

```
 git reset @~
 git add .
 git commit --interactive
```

Or actually just `git commit`, since you already added what you wanted.
That would still open an editor for you to enter the commit message again.

Answer (score 2):

An extension on @VonC answer with an example of the situation:

```
mkdir git_example
cd git_example
git init
echo first > first
git add first 
git commit -m "initial"
git tag initial

echo "How do I see this change while editing in interacive rebase" > second
git add second 
git commit -m "second"

echo third > third
git add third 
git commit -m "third"

git rebase -i initial
    e 66127f1 second
    pick 70c0b50 third

git reset HEAD~
git add .
git commit  
# NOT commit --amend
# The commit message will be empty, that's ok
git rebase --continue
```

Being explicit about one thing that messed my mind a bit:

After the reset do a `commit` **not** a `commit --amend` or that will mess up the initial commit.

Comment: Interesting example, in addition to my answer. +1