# Git command to reset only index and working tree not the HEAD

Tags: git

This question is a follow up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44513186/how-do-i-edit-a-commit-with-interactive-rebase-as-uncommited). It's trying to find a simpler way to edit commits during an interactively rebase.

Here is a full example where the problem can be seen:

```
mkdir git_example
cd git_example
git init
echo first > first
git add first 
git commit -m "initial"
git tag initial

echo "How do I see this change while editing in interacive rebase" > second
git add second 
git commit -m "second"

echo third > third
git add third 
git commit -m "third"

git rebase -i initial
    e 66127f1 second
    pick 70c0b50 third

git reset HEAD~
git add .
git commit  
# NOT commit --amend
# The commit message will be empty, that's ok
git rebase --continue
```

The problem lays in `git reset HEAD~` and the fact that it changes the HEAD. This destroys the commit message from this commit and leaves us with `# The commit message will be empty, that's ok`.

Is there a way to reset the index and working tree but keep the HEAD intact?

The help for `git reset -h` list all combinations instead of that one.

Answer (score 3):

#### Using `git-restore`

> Is there a way to reset the index and working tree but keep the HEAD intact?

That's exactly what the new [`git-restore`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/git-restore.txt) command is for:

> Restore specified paths in the working tree with some contents from a restore source.

By default, [`git-restore`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/git-restore.txt) will only modify the working tree, but you can tell it to update the index as well:

> The command can also be used to restore the content in the index with `--staged`, or restore both the working tree and the index with `--staged --worktree`.

You may notice that this behavior overlaps directly with `git-reset`; the key difference between the two is that `git-restore` won't touch the `HEAD` reference, which is exactly what you want.

The command would then be:

```
git restore --staged --worktree --source HEAD~
```

Keep in mind that `git restore` is still being actively worked on (the documentation lists it as experimental) but this is definitely the way forward.

#### Using `git-show` or `git-diff`

There's also another way. If you want to see the patch associated to the current commit during an interactive rebase, you don't have to reset the index to `HEAD~` to do it; instead, you can simply use [`git-show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) or [`git-diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

Your workflow would then be:

```
git rebase -i initial
    e 66127f1 second
    pick 70c0b50 third
git show
# or
git diff HEAD~..HEAD
# Look at the patch generated by 66127f1
# Modify the files in your working directory as needed 
git add .
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: Looks like `git-restore` is not in a stable release in the current moment in time. Will accept the answer as soon as I can test it with a stable git release.

Comment: @TheMeaningfulEngineer You can also use `git-show` or `git-diff` in the meantime. See the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to rely on experimental features (and need this today rather than whenever `restore` is done being experimental), the simplest way is probably

```
git rm -r :/:
git checkout HEAD~ -- :/:
git add :/:
```

Note I'm using `:/:` to reference "the root of the worktree" regardless of the current working directory.  If you know you're in the root, you can just use `.`